# how to put condition on xsl:result-document output according to attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

i am transforming XML using Saxon parser.i have to generate same output with two place that i am able to do that.i want to put the condition like if count attribute value is 0 then it should not generate any output file. my input file is

```
             <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soapenv:Body>
<ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponsexmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <Document xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
   <Attributes>
   <Attribute name="duration">0:00:00.789</Attribute>
   <Attribute name="count">0</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="entity">SourcingRequest</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="mode">XML</Attribute>
     <Attribute name="version">http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01</Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Content>
   <ExportXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"/>
   </Content>
   </Document>
  </ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

my xsl file is like this .

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output  indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
     <xsl:param name="pDest" select="'file:///c:/temp/'"/>
     <xsl:param name="pDest1" select="'file:///c:/'"/>

  <xsl:template match="*:field">
     <xsl:element name="{lower-case(@name)}">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>    
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:result-document
            href="{$pDest}requsition_{format-date(current-date(),'[D01]_[M01]')}.xml">
        <JobPositionPostings>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*:Content[1]" />
        </JobPositionPostings>
     </xsl:result-document>
     <xsl:result-document
            href="{$pDest1}requsition_{format-date(current-date(),'[D01]_[M01]')}.xml">
        <JobPositionPostings>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*:Content[1]" />
        </JobPositionPostings>
     </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*:record">
  <!--doing rest operation if attribute count not equal to 0 -->
  </xsl:template> 

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Why do you have template rules that match *:record and *:field when there are no matching elements in your source document? How do you expect a condition in the template that matches *:record to affect the xsl:result-document calls in a different template? What output do you want to produce? I'm downvoting the question because it's incomprehensible - and because you couldn't even take the trouble to format your code legibly.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.if there is some value then i have to transform flat xml to nested xml so only condition is there "*:record". nested part is working fine i just want if that count value is 0 then no file should generate else it ll preform nested transform like this.is it possible in single xsl transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to replace the template

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:result-document
            href="{$pDest}requsition_{format-date(current-date(),'[D01]_[M01]')}.xml">
        <JobPositionPostings>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*:Content[1]" />
        </JobPositionPostings>
     </xsl:result-document>
     <xsl:result-document
            href="{$pDest1}requsition_{format-date(current-date(),'[D01]_[M01]')}.xml">
        <JobPositionPostings>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*:Content[1]" />
        </JobPositionPostings>
     </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
```

somehow with

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse/df:Document/df:Attributes/df:Attribute[@name = 'count'] != 0">
     <xsl:result-document
            href="{$pDest}requsition_{format-date(current-date(),'[D01]_[M01]')}.xml">
        <JobPositionPostings>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*:Content[1]" />
        </JobPositionPostings>
     </xsl:result-document>
     <xsl:result-document
            href="{$pDest1}requsition_{format-date(current-date(),'[D01]_[M01]')}.xml">
        <JobPositionPostings>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*:Content[1]" />
        </JobPositionPostings>
     </xsl:result-document>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

where you additionally declare

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
  xmlns:df="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
  exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv ns1 df"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
```

That way the two `xsl:result-document` instructions you have are only executed if the condition is true.